# Int number 0000 cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting

I have a starting number to work from which is 0000 and increment it by one, i have that done, but the result is 1,2,3 instead of 0001,0002,0003 etc. How can I achieve this?

I use this string:

```
stringa = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d",score];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
stringa = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %04d",score];
```

should do what you want.

"4" is the (minimum) field width, and the "0" is for padding with zeroes instead of spaces.
`stringWithFormat` understands (almost) all the "printf" formats 
(which are described in detail here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html ).

Comment: it must work perfectly, I had suggest that solution, if I would have been faster. when you reach the `9999` and it turns into `10000` it will be `10000`, because no leading zero will be needed anymore.

Comment: @StefanoRomani: You are welcome. (I took the liberty and edited the question tags, because the question is not really cocos2d-related.)